# Ajax program not functioning on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I wrote the following code for a small ajax program.
I am able to execute it On IE 11 but not on chrome and firefox

html file:

```
<html>
<head><title>Ajax Page</title>
<script>
function ajax_handler(){
    try
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e1){
        try{
            var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e2){
            try{
                var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e3){
                alert('ajax not supported');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    var rollno = document.getElementById("roll").value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getresult;
    var url = 'ajax.php?roll='+rollno;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);       
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
function getresult(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var sp = document.getElementById("result");
            sp.innerText=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    Enter roll:<input type="text" id="roll" name="roll" /><br />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="ajax_handler()" /><br />
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding PHP page:

```
<?php
$roll = $_GET['roll'];
if($roll == 1001){
    echo 'passed';
}
?>
```

As it can be seen my PHP program does not send back any 
XML data.It only sends back text.What is the mistake that I am doing

Comment: Browser devtools network tab.  The request/response can be seen and debugged there.  What is in the response?

Comment: I don't think this would work on any browser seeing that you're trying to access a local variable from an unrelated function.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yup.just figured it out.Thank you

Comment: @James Thanks.that helped me find out the blunder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a mistake of using **`var`** while declaring XMLHttpRequest object.
Removed it and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Upon trying out the code, I realized that it actually does work on chrome but the problem lies with the `getresult()` function. It would be safer to define the onreadystatechange function inline rather than defining it elsewhere. The error is mostly the fact that the onreadystatechange does not know about the xmlhttp object. Here is the code.

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Ajax Page</title>
    <script>
    function ajax_handler(){
        try
        {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log('success');
}catch(e1){
    try{
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e2){
        try{
            var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e3){
            alert('ajax not supported');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
var rollno = document.getElementById("roll").value;
//function is defined inline rather than defining it elswhere and calling the function
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        var sp = document.getElementById("result");
        sp.innerText=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
var url = 'test.php?roll='+rollno;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);       
xmlhttp.send(); 
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
Enter roll:<input type="text" id="roll" name="roll" /><br />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="ajax_handler()" /><br />
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```